# Is it possible to create a dynamic grid based layout using iOS AutoLayout?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout, grid-layout

I using a tableview to present some times. I want to create cells that display a variable number of labels in a grid like format. See example below:

[image: Label Grid]

If I was not already using a `UITableView` I could obviously use `UICollectionView` to achieve this.

I'm using `UITableView` because I want to show rows with section headers. I only want the grid layout within the table cells not the table itself.

I'm fairly new to AutoLayout and have been using it fairly successful throughout my app but I'm not sure how you could achieve a dynamic layout like this?

Things to note:

- Variable number of labels
- Device might be rotated so it would need to show a dynamic number of labels horizontally based on the available width.
- All the labels need to align in a grid (see screenshot)

Is this possible using AutoLayout?

Comment: Yes absolutely possible... http://www.oliverfoggin.com/an-auto-layout-experiment/ Just having a look now will write an answer.

Comment: What's the maximum number of "columns" you would want? Or will that change depending on the content?

Comment: @Fogmeister The number of columns would need to be dynamic based on the bounds.width of the superview. Ideally it would show 4 columns on an iPhone in portrait. As it's just times all the labels can have the same width.

Comment: @Fogmeister That link looks really interesting. I look forward to your answer.

Comment: @Fogmeister I've looked at your project and it looks impressive. Though it does require up-front knowledge of the number of columns which I won't necessarily know as all my labels would have an intrinsic content size. Also it seems like a lot of work just to use AutoLayout. Would it not have been easier just to managed the frames yourself. At the moment I've decided to not use AutoLayout for this kind of layout unless I find a way to achieve the required results.

Comment: The project was an exercise in using AutoLayout just to see what I could do :) If you create a custom UITableViewCell subclass it should be fairly straight forward to place 4 labels in it. Where are you getting stuck? Also, is there any particular reason you can't use UICollectionView for this? You can use supplementary views in a UICollectionView.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33562/discussion-between-camsoft-and-fogmeister)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used UICollectionView in the end instead of UITableView and implemented Header views that mimic UITableView section headers.